# MOSS 2007 migration to SP 2010 foundation (The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted)

Tags: 2010, 2007

I just migrated from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010 foundations. I installed SharePoint on server and used a separate SQL server. I did get some errors during upgrade due to webparts/assemblies/features being missing but I don't think this is causing the error.

I can't get to the default homepage, I get the error below. I can get to other sub-sites or other sections of the main site. I have tried using SharePoint designer to look at the page but it won't work either.

I looked at the log file for the correlation ID but it doesn't have any other helpful data.

```
The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 55fb2c34-6559-4db8-ae1a-92599cc67ea6

Date and Time: 3/4/2016 2:59:00 PM
```

Comment: are you using custom master page? check this https://isharepoint.wordpress.com/tag/the-file-or-folder-name-contains-characters-that-are-not-permitted/

Comment: Not sure, SharePoint is not my strength. That blog post doesn't say how to check the file or where its located, do you know?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up deleting the default.aspx page and created another one.